# How can I instantiate multiple objects for different lines of a SQLITE database in Java?

Tags: java, database, sqlite

I think I can keep this pretty simple. I have a GUI from JavaFX that displays information regarding example "tenants" from a sqlite database, however, I can only get it to populate one row with the first information available at the top of the table using my current method that I've writen to query the database. This is because I need to instantiate what I currently have as a "Tenant" object, that takes a name, Lease Length, Rent Paid (0/1) and a Property ID associated with that Tenant.

How can I have the table populate with everything in the Sqlite Database in Java if I only have access to single lines without a while loop.

For example

```
    rs.getString("name");
    rs.getDouble("leaseLength");
    rs.getBoolean("rentPaid");
    rs.getString("PropertyID");
```

All of this only returns the first value without a while loop to loop over the entire thing, but I need it to return multiple values to store in different variables so I can instantiate multiple objects from the information in said variables. When I call my queryTenants() method - it manages to grab the values necessary from the first tenant, but I don't see a way forward to continue querying to instantiate and get information from as many tenants as there are/will be in the .db file.

Any ideas?

Here is a screenshot of the display table:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0YYV.png)

This is the result of querying the Sqlite database and grabbing all the info for the tenant, and using the 4 fields to instantiate a Tenant object that I've defined elsewhere. But I can only do one tenant, and if I call the method twice, it populates the table with the same tenant because it can still only grab the first one off the list in the .db file.

Sorry if this is a poor question, or if the information is lacking. I'm pretty new to this and only started coding in July. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Maybe you could [edit] your question and post a [mcve] ?

Comment: https://github.com/sedj601/SQLitePersonTableViewExample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple times you mention *not* using a `while` loop and that's where your issue lies. In order to get all the results from a `ResultSet` you need to use a `while` loop. For example:

```java
List<Tenant> getTenants() throws SQLException {
  try (Statement stat = connection.createStatement();
       ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM tenants")) {

    List<Tenant> tenants = new ArrayList<>();

    while (rs.next()) {
      Tenant tenant = new Tenant();
      tenant.setName(rs.getString("name"));
      tenant.setLeaseLength(rs.getDouble("leaseLength"));
      tenant.setRentPaid(rs.getBoolean("rentPaid"));
      tenant.setPropertyId(rs.getString("PropertyID"));

      tenants.add(tenant);
    }

    return tenants;
  }
}
```

Some notes:

- Each time `ResultSet#next()` returns `true` an internal "cursor" moves to the next row of data.
- The above uses the [try-with-resources statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).
- If your query has parameters it's strongly encouraged to use a [`PreparedStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) instead of a `Statement`. This helps prevent common issues, not least of which is [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).